# Plotly Dataframe with multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to plot a df which looks like the following:

```
    200    300    400    500
0   1.2    2.2   12.3    4.2
1   2.7   13.1    9.8    3.3
2   1.8    1.5    5.1    9.8
3   3.9    3.3   12.1   12.2
```

Here is the code I am using: (courtesy: eyllanesc, thanks)

```
import plotly


xy=px.line(self.predata,x=self.predata.columns.values,y=self.predata.index.values)
PlotlyPlot(self,xy)

def PlotlyPlot(self,tobeshown):

    raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />' 
    raw_html += '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>' 
    raw_html += '<body>' 
    raw_html += plotly.offline.plot(tobeshown, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div', ) 
    raw_html += '</body></html>'
    self.graphicsView.setHtml(raw_html)
```

I want the X axis to be the header (200,300,400...) and the Y axis to be the values in each of the rows (1.2,2.2 ...) in the plot. While this works for 1 line with length of x = length of y, it doesn't work otherwise.
When I run this, I get an error:

```
All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 243, whereas the length of previous arguments ['x'] is 143.
```

Comment: I don't know about plotly, but you can do `df.T.plot()` to get what you want.

Comment: I understood how to implement this in matploblib, but unfortunately, it doesn't support hover to view data and I also wanted to implement select data points on click and the index locations (column and row number) will be pointed out.

Comment: What I was trying to say is what you want to plot is `df.T`...

Comment: Okay, and how to do that? I transposed it and it says 'x' argument is 243 and 'y' is 143 now, I think I did something wrong

Comment: Any help appreciated

Comment: Bump. Looking for a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IUUC Here you have two options: a loop or convert your df from wide to long and use `plotly.express`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

from io import StringIO
df = """   200    300    400    500
0   1.2    2.2   12.3    4.2
1   2.7   13.1    9.8    3.3
2   1.8    1.5    5.1    9.8
3   3.9    3.3   12.1   12.2"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), delim_whitespace=True)

# as you want columns on x axis
df = df.T
```

## loop

```py
fig = go.Figure()
for col in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=df.index, y=df[col]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

## `plotly.express`

```py
df['x'] = df.index
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars="x", value_vars=df.columns[:-1])
px.line(df_melt, x="x", y="value",color="variable")
```

[image]